# Is it possible to copy files from a Host os to a Guest OS which is running in the virtualbox ? (Not Folder sharing)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, c, file-copy, c++

As per my understanding there is an option called Shared Folder. But I am not referring to that. Here my Guest OS is Linux and my Host OS is windows. I am using virtualbox to run the Guest OS. I need to run a simple application(C/C++) in the Linux which is running in the virtualbox.

The function syntax can be something like below

```
fun_copy(file_from_host_os,dest_path_guest_os)
{
  //Implementation
}
```

Here:

- `file_from_host_os`: The file (eg: foo.txt) present inside the windows directory.
- `dest_path_guest_os` - Location of the destination path(eg: /home/) inside the linux (running in the virtualbox)

I am a newbie into this forum. Correct me if something is wrong from side. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the overall goal to transfer data from the Windows host to the Linux guest?  In that case something like [`pscp` or `psftp`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) from Windows may be useful.  If this is a C or C++ programming question, it may be better suited on the StackOverflow site.

Comment: @kusalananda :  Is it possible to link this question to StackOverflow site or do I need to ask the same question there ?

Comment: The fact that the Linux host is a VirtualBox guest is not relevant. The answer would be the same if it had been a separate physical machine, so you might as well remove all mentionings of VirtualBox and shared folders. It is still not clear to me whether the topic of this question is "How do I write C or C++ code to transfer a file?" (a programming question possibly relevant on StackOverflow, but see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or "How may I transfer a file (by any means)?" (a question possibly relevant to _this_ site, or to the SuperUser site).

Comment: Is sharing a network an option? If the host and guest share a network, one of them can run a service that makes copying the file possible.

Comment: I think a relevant question (that would give the answer that you need) would be "How do I transfer files from Microsoft's Windows to Gnu/Linux via a network?"

Answer (score 1):

When I need to copy files from/to guest to/from host, I use the python module `SimpleHTTPServer`.

To copy from guest to host:

- Activate the host private network (often addresses in 192.168.56.x)
- From one guest,

  - get the ip: `ip a | grep 192.168.56`
  - launch a simple http server : `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
- From the host, open firefox and connect to the guest: `firefox 192.168.56.xx:8000`